# Как в PyCharm вставить букву в середину слова

Tags: pycharm

Пишу в PyCharm и иногда нужно внести правки в написанный код, но в PyCharm внося изменения каждая последующая буквально заменяет предыдущую, вместо того что бы встать в середину слова

Comment: Нажмите клавишу Insert на клавиатуре?

Comment: Не совсем, это ты имеешь простую вставку? Я же про то что иногда вместо разделителя происходит захват буквы в такой квадратик и когда ты что то печатаешь то твои новые буквы заменяют старые и по этому корректно отредактировать код не получается, а как сделать так, что бы происходил не захват буквы, а разделение между буквами

Comment: Ну, всё ещё нажмите клавишу Insert на клавиатуре?

Comment: клавиша insert помогла